# Calling rsync from Python versus bash script

Tags: python, bash, rsync

I have an rsync call that I've moved from a bash script into a python script. Strangely, the rsync is having issues when called from python:

Here's the bash call:

```
 rsync --delete --exclude .svn -avz /home/app/resources/$RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE /home/elc/app/omap3/$RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE/resources
```

Here's the Python call:

```
 os.system("rsync --delete --exclude .svn -avz /home/app/resources/$RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE /home/elc/app/omap3/$RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE/resources")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are the issues you are having? Does it emit any error messages?

Comment: you have to `export` the variable `$RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE` before launching python.

Answer (score 4):

My first suspicion would be that the environment variables you are referencing are not set in the shell spawned for the `os.system` call. You might try debugging by making Python spawn an `echo` command in order to verify that the results are what you expect.

```
os.system("echo $RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE")
```

If the environment variable is present you should see its contents printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the call like so:

```
resources_to_update = os.environ["RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE"]
os.system("rsync --delete --exclude .svn -avz /home/app/resources/%s /home/elc/app/omap3/%s/resources" % (resources_to_update, resources_to_update))
```

or for 2.7+

```
os.system("rsync --delete --exclude .svn -avz /home/app/resources/{0} /home/elc/app/omap3/{0}/resources".format(os.environ["RESOURCES_TO_UPDATE"]))
```